# How to pass part of an argument to a gnu parallel command

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to run a GNU parallel command and pass it a bunch of dates, something like this but a more complex command:

```
parallel '/some/binary {}' ::: 20131017 20131018
```

this works, but then i need the dates to span two different months and the command should look like this for argument 20131018:

```
'/some/binary 201310/20131018'
```

so it split off the first part of the argument..how can I achieve this effect? Thinking in terms of bash variables I imagine:

```
'/some/binary {:4}/{}' ::: 20130910 20131018 etc...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command for parallel is interpreted as a shell command, so you can just do

```
parallel --gnu 'var="{}"; /some/binary "${var:0:6}/$var"' ::: 20131017 20131018
```

This will execute

```
/some/binary 201310/20131017
/some/binary 201310/20131018
```

Answer (score 1):

From 20140722 you can:

```
parallel /some/binary '{=s/..$//=}'/{} ::: 20131017 20131018
```

Answer (score 0):

For pure ugly, don't forget about `awk` to munge data with the result piped to parallel:

```
$ echo 20131017 > foo
$ echo 20131018 >> foo
$ awk '{printf "%s/%s\n", substr($1,0,4), $1}' foo | parallel echo
```

Ugly aside, this is pipeline friendly.  A plain `print` along with some `OFS` magic would work more cleanly than `printf` I suspect.  You could alternately use `sed` if that's your jam.

That said, I'd personally modify `/some/binary` to not expect such wonky input.